# Functions for system status C#

Tags: c#, mono, system-status

I'm looking for general system state functions for Mono. Things I need are:

- Memory (available, total)
- Free disk space
- IP Number
- External IP
- Running processes / services / daemons

How do I get those?

Thanks in advance,

Yvan

Comment: To be honest, after supplying my answer I am surprised you did not check it out for yourself! But anyway...

Comment: Thanks, I thought there might be an unified class which contained all system access functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the order of your list requirements, I have outlined the necessary namespaces for those functions. Since you did not supply the platform...

- Memory (available/total) Perhaps, System.Environment class?
- Free Disk Space (Mono.Unix.DriveInfo namespace) System.IO.DriveInfo?
- IP number (Mono.Unix.UnixEndPoint) System.Net.EndPoint?
- External IP address - not sure about this, this would be based on the output of `ipconfig` or `ifconfig`, or check the routing tables.
- Running processes/services/daemons (Mono.Unix.UnixProcess) System.Diagnostics.Process class?

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.