# How can I get the free space on a USB flash drive in VB.NET under Mono?

Tags: linux, vb.net, mono

I am using vb.net (framework 2.0) to develop a console application on Windows which I want to then run under Mono on Debian as well.  I am using System.IO.DriveInfo to get the free space on a USB flash drive.  Under Windows this works fine:

`Dim drv As New System.IO.DriveInfo("I:\")`

On Linux this generates an exception:

`Dim drv As New System.IO.DriveInfo("/mnt/usb_flash")`

It appears from googling that DriveInfo is not well implemented under Mono.

How can I get the free space from a USB flash drive in VB.NET under Mono?

Thanks.

Comment: Already answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168191/functions-for-system-status-c-sharp

Comment: Which exception do you get? And try prepending a slash: Dim drv As New System.IO.DriveInfo("/mnt/usb_flash")

Comment: Rolf - Sorry, that is just my typo, in the working code the actual path is passed in as an argumentand includes the root slash.

Comment: Andrew - Hmm...so I need to install and reference the Mono framework in order to use Mono.Unix.DriveInfo.  Can I reference Mono framework as well as dot net or must I switch from one to the other?